# Telnet against Aastra Mx-One

Tags: .net, telnet, pbx

I am trying to connect to an MX-One pbx with telnet. 
The strange thing is that when I am using hyperterminal I can connect and I get the login: promt in return. It just works as does the DOS telnet app.

But when I try the login with our C# application (which is used against the Aastra MD110 pbx, to collect the same data with the same format) using nSoftwares IP*Works Telnet component I can connect but does not get anything in return even though it connects successfully.

Anyone has any idees or pointers on where to start searching for the solution.

Thanks in advance
Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One start point will be trying [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It's a protocol analizer. With this you could trace what are you realy sending to the server and what is the server response.